# How to properly scale a face into itself to bevel

Tags: modeling, transforms

I really don't know how to describe this, but what I want to happen is all of the vertices being the same amount away from relative vertices. Instead what is happening when I scale the face by extruding and then scaling is weird uneven proportions. I've tried using the I shortcut (and the II shortcut) but it just glitches because the shape is so complex. I've included an image from the front point of view. You can see at the left where the neck ends that there is plenty of space, but the chin is behind the other layer.

[image]

Comment: Did you apply the scale to the object (Ctrl-A > Scale in Object mode) before you tried to extrude and scale it?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you share your blend file? https://blend-exchange.com